# Install mySQL data using ftp?

Tags: mysql, magento

I am trying to install magento (open source e-commerce platform) sample data on my webhost.

I have uploaded the file magento_sample_data.sql via ftp, and setup a new database and have assigned it to a user.

How do I get the sample data into my empty database?

Answer (score 0):

Go to control panel/CPanle or whatever and then go to **phpmyadmin** from there select your database and then click on the "**import**" link and then upload the sql file and press **Go** button, this will import your data into the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mysql-software.

For example phpmyadmin.

If it's not already installed, just download it and extract it on your webspace, configure it and do an import with your .sql file.